# Make Android app fullscreen: API 15+

Tags: android

What's the best way to make an Android app fullscreen for Api Levels 15+?

I am currently using this code but I am not sure if this is compatible with API level 15:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: `I am not sure if this is compatible with API level 15` Then, **test it** on API level 15.

Comment: Have you tested it on API Level 15?

Answer (score 1):

I have always do this on every API:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The first Line hide `ActionBar` and the second one hide `NotificationBar`

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your code before setContentView() method in onCreate()