# Hide status bar in android api level 15?

Tags: android

I need to hide status bar in my android app to make it full screen. So i looked at some questions here as well as some of googles developer resources. Looking at a training page of google I found something odd.

This page https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html which is about hiding status bar is divided into two parts. First is about how to do it in android level 4.0(API level 14) and lower while second is about how to do it in android level 4.1 (API level 16) or higher. Nowhere does it talk about how to do it in API level 15. Can it not be done in api level 15? Or one of the two methods will work in API level 15 as well?

The app i am working on has minimum api level of 17 so it was not a problem for this app. But i would like to know about it for future reference.

Comment: Try read this two links one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439078/make-android-app-fullscreen-api-15 and two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637959/android-fullscreen-activity-api-14-android-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```